# nested append operation goes wrong?

Tags: python, list, nested, append

I have two lists: `a = [0], b = [[0,1]]`, I want to append 2 to `a` first, then append `a` to `b`. So `b` should be `[[0,1], [0,2]]`.
Operations like this work well:

```
a.append(2)
b.append(a)
```

but when I tried to combine them:

```
b.append(a.append(2))
```

I got the results:

```
a = [0, 2], b = [[0, 1], None]
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: try it yourself, ``print(a.append(2))``

Comment: `append` works inplace and returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the comments, `a.append(2)` only appends `2` to the list `a`, but it doesn't actually return it. An append operation that doesn't modify the original list but returns a new list with the appended value can be written simply with the `+`-operator.

```py
>>> a, b = [0], [[0, 1]]
>>> b.append(a + [2])  # The list that is returned to the append function is [0, 2]
>>> a
[0]
>>> b
[[0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the comments already answered your question: the `append()` method modifies the list in place instead of creating a new one, and its return type is `None`. If you still want to do the operation in a single line, you could use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
a, b = [0], [[0, 1]]
b.append(a := a + [2])
print(a, b)
# [0, 2] [[0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent, exactly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga interesting! How does it differ?

Comment: Well, you aren't modifying the list at `a` in place, rather, you are reassigning a new list

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have check the `id` of `a` before and after the operation, it differs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine those you might make your own function,

```
def append_ret(x, value):
  x.append(value)
  return x
```

doing the operation and returning the 'appended' container.

```
append_ret(b, append_ret(a,1))
```

Comment: You should probably give the function a slightly different name, for example `append_ret`, as to avoid confusion with the member function on lists and explicitly state the changed behaviour as compared to the normal `append`-function.